# php loading different structure than source code

Tags: php, templates

I was trying to code in a conditional statement into a template file and had a bit of an issue.

This is the code in the file

```
     else
            {
                echo('<div class="thumbList"><a href="' . the_permalink() . '"><div class="prod-thumb">' . the_post_thumbnail( 'product-thumb', array( 'class' => 'product-thumb' ) ) . '</div> 
    <div class="prod-info">
        <span class="prod-ttl"><h4>' . the_title() . '</h4></span>
        <table class="prod-table">
            <tr class="odd"><td class="desc-title"><strong>Design No.:</strong></td><td><span>' .  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'prod_id', true) . '</span></td></tr>
            <tr class="odd"><td class="desc-title"><strong>Product Status:</strong></td><td><span>' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'prod_status', true) . '</span></td></tr>
            <tr class="even"><td class="desc-title"><strong>Style:</strong></td><td><span>' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'prod_style', true) . '</span></td></tr>
            <tr class="odd"><td class="desc-title"><strong>Size:</strong></td><td><span>' . wpautop(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'prod_sizes', true)) . '</span></td></tr>' . ($post->prod_price && $post->prod_sale == ""?('<tr class="even"><td class="desc-title">Original Price:</td><td><span>' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'prod_price', true) . '</span></td></tr>'):($post->prod_sale != ""?('<tr class="even"><td class="desc-title"><div style="font-weight:bold;color:#FF2929;">Sale Price:</div></td><td><span>' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'prod_sale', true) . '</span></td></tr><tr class="even"><td class="desc-title"><div style="text-decoration:line-through;color:#8C8C8C;">Original Price:</div></td><td><span><div style="text-decoration:line-through;color:#8C8C8C;">' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'prod_price', true) . '</div></span></td></tr>') : '<p></p>')) . '</table>
        <br/><br/>' . ($post->post_content?('<div class="resp320Hid" style="color:#b8b042;"><div class="entry">' . the_content() . '</div></div>'):'') . '<div class="resp320Hid"><p><span>Click here to view more Details</span></p></div></div>' . ($post->post_content?('<div class="resp320Show" style="clear:both;"><div class="entry">' . the_content() . '</div></div>'):'') . '<div class="resp320Show"><p><span>Click here to view more Details</span></p></div></a></div>'
);}
```

This is what it's supposed to output

```
    <div class="thumbList">                 
<a href="http://dev.imagecarpets.com/products/new-arrival/gabbeh-rug-12767/">           
    <div class="prod-thumb">                
        <img width="250" height="388" src="http://dev.imagecarpets.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Gabbeh_12767__4.01x6.06-250x388.jpg" class="attachment-product-thumb wp-post-image" alt="Gabbeh_12767__4.01x6.06" />      </div>  
    <div class="prod-info">
        <span class="prod-ttl"><h4>Gabbeh Rug-12767</h4></span>
        <table class="prod-table">
            <tr class="odd"><td class="desc-title"><strong>Design No.:</strong></td><td><span>12767</span></td></tr>
            <tr class="odd"><td class="desc-title"><strong>Product Status:</strong></td><td><span>In Stock</span></td></tr>
            <tr class="even"><td class="desc-title"><strong>Style:</strong></td><td><span>Allover</span></td></tr>
            <tr class="odd"><td class="desc-title"><strong>Size:</strong></td><td><span><p>4.1 x 6.6</p>
```

Click here to view more Details

Click here to view more Details

```
</a>
```

But instead, for some reason, when the page loads in the browser, this is what it looks like:

```
    http://dev.imagecarpets.com/products/contemporary-rug/moroccan-rug-140105/<img width="450" height="534" src="http://dev.imagecarpets.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Morracan_140105_8.05X10.00DRK-1-450x534.jpg" class="product-thumb wp-post-image" alt="Morracan_140105_8.05X10.00DRK (1)" />Moroccan Rug-140105<div class="thumbList"><a href=""><div class="prod-thumb"></div>  
    <div class="prod-info">
        <span class="prod-ttl"><h4></h4></span>
        <table class="prod-table">
            <tr class="odd"><td class="desc-title"><strong>Design No.:</strong></td><td><span>140105</span></td></tr>
            <tr class="odd"><td class="desc-title"><strong>Product Status:</strong></td><td><span>In Stock</span></td></tr>
            <tr class="even"><td class="desc-title"><strong>Style:</strong></td><td><span>Allover</span></td></tr>
            <tr class="odd"><td class="desc-title"><strong>Size:</strong></td><td><span><p>8.5 x 10</p>
```

Click here to view more Details

Click here to view more Details

The thumbnail image and permalink are loaded outside the thumblist class as it was intended and the link doesnt turn into a link. It just prints the path unformatted. I probably did something dumb but I can't figure it out. Can anyone help

Comment: Can you please reformat your question using the code tags?  It looks like you're not closing your initial <a> tag though.

Comment: I did use a code tag, it's 3 snippets of code inside 3 of those scroll boxes. I followed the directions for the code thing unless you mean doing something else. Also in the lline before  the closing brackets, the closing tag for the link is there at the end

Answer (score 1):

You're using template tags within an echo statement that themselves echo a value. You need to use the versions that `return` their value.

`the_permalink()` should be [`get_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink), `the_post_thumbnail` should be [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail), `the_title` should be [`the_title( '', '', false )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title), `the_content` should be [`get_the_content()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content).

Comment: What should go in the parenthesis for this part

get_the_post_thumbnail( 'product-thumb', array( 'class' => 'product-thumb' ) )

Comment: The first argument is post ID: `get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'product-thumb', array( 'class' => 'product-thumb' ) )`

Comment: GOt it thanks. One last thing, when replacing the_permalink() with get_permalink, on a click leads to URI/get_permalink which leads to a 404 page. Was I supposed to set something else?


EDIT: Nvm fixed it. Forgot the paranthesis